# Angular and ionic not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

At the index.html i've got:

```
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Still, i get angular is not defined, and ionic is not defined at ionic serve -lsc...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/) at the very least, before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why so many down votes?I've already read the documentation and it doesn't point me to a solution.

Comment: Please provide a full woking code example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the trick:

```
bower install angular
```

At ionic's project folder.